# Can't round iPhone icon corners using Phonegap

Tags: iphone, cordova, ios7

When I run my app on the simulator my app icon is square rather than rounded corners -- I thought iOS automatically added the rounded corners as a mask?

I'm using PhoneGap to build this and I turned the 'pre-rendered icon' setting to false. I also ensured that my plist file does not have an entry for UIPrerenderedIcon.

In Xcode I created an 'App Icon Set' that has the necessary sizes for iPhone Retina.

What am I missing here? (I'm new to iOS development so I don't know what a lot of this stuff actually means...)

Comment: Have you tried running on a device? It sounds more likely to be a bug on the Simulator

Comment: was able to get my hands on a device and it made the icon slightly smaller and rounded the corners, but created a black background where the icon had been shrunk... Definitely less than ideal...

Comment: Is the app built in Phonegap Build or through Xcode?

Comment: @WillshawMedia its built through Xcode